# What path does mean in fastai

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, kaggle, fast-ai

I want to use ImageDataBunch.from_lists but I don't know what path does mean (in fastai).

For example, I need to to write

```
data = ImageDataBunch.from_lists(path, fnames, labels=labels, ds_tfms=tfms, size=256)
```

fnames are file names. For example, fname = array(['/kaggle/input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train/cat.0.jpg',
       '/kaggle/input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train/cat.1.jpg',
       '/kaggle/input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train/cat.10.jpg',
       '/kaggle/input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train/cat.100.jpg', ...,
       '/kaggle/input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train/dog.9997.jpg',
       '/kaggle/input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train/dog.9998.jpg',
       '/kaggle/input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train/dog.9999.jpg',
       '/kaggle/input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train/train'], dtype='

```
labels = np.array([(0 if 'cat' in fname else 1) for fname in fnames])
```

But I don't know why do we need **path** in data = ImageDataBunch.from_lists(**path**, fnames, labels=labels, ds_tfms=tfms, size=256)

What do I need to write as **path**?

Answer (score 0):

Path here refers to your training dataset directory where your data is located. 
For eg in your example above:-
**kaggle/input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train** is your path. 
 The api will go through all the files in this path and then label them according to your list that you've provided.